# How to pass variable from texbox to php function () located in other file using webix post() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, webix

I have test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Loading from DB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codebase/webix.css" type="text/css"> 
    <script src="codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <style>
.submitButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 11px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
    box-shadow: 11px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #599bb3), color-stop(1, #408c99));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#599bb3', endColorstr='#408c99',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#599bb3;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
}
.submitButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #408c99), color-stop(1, #599bb3));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#408c99', endColorstr='#599bb3',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#408c99;
}
.submitButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body background="images/background_mono1.jpg">

<img src="images/azerconnect_logo.jpg" width="200" height="116" alt=""/>

<?php
//$filename = getcwd() . "/test.txt";
//echo $filename;
//$line_i_am_looking_for = 5;
//$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
//$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = '6my modified line';
//file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
require_once('functions.php');
?>


                <form action="submit.php" method="post">
                <textarea placeholder="WO number (separate with comma if several)"  rows="4" cols="30" name="WO_textarea" ></textarea>
                <input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Submit">
                </form>
                <hr>

        <div class='header_comment'>Test WO info</div>
        <div id="testA" style='height:650px'></div>
        <div id="testB" style='height:350px'></div>
        <hr>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        webix.ready(function(){

                 grida = webix.ui({
                                container:"testA",
                                view:"datatable",
                                columns:[
                                        { id:"idWO",    header:"Work Order ID",         width:200 },
                                        { id:"WO_STATUS",header:"Work Order Status",            width:120 }
                                //      { id:"size",    header:"Size" ,                 width:80  },
                                //      { id:"architecture",    header:"PC",    width:60  }
                                ],
                                autowidth:true,
                                autoheight:true,
                                url: "data/data.php",

                        });


          gridb = webix.ui({
                                container:"testB",
                 "view": "form",
  "elements": [
    {
      "view": "textarea",
      "name": "woNumber",
      "id": "textarea",
      "label": "",
      "width": 300,
      "height": 200,
      "options": [
        "onViewResize"
      ],
      "value": "",
      "placeholder": "WO number (separate with comma if several)",
      "labelPosition": "top"
    },
    {
      "view": "button",
      "name": "getWODetails",
      "label": "",
      "value": "Submit",
      "options": [
        "autowidth:true"
      ],
                on:{
                    onItemClick:function(id){
                        webix.message("Sikim BLEAT'!!!");
                    saveToFile();
/*                  onItemClick: getTextareaData;
*/
                    }
                },
      "labelPosition": "top"

    },
    {
      "view": "button",
      "id": "button1",
      "name": "getWODetails",
      "label": "",
      "value": "Passss",
      "options": [
        "autowidth:true"
      ],
                                on:{
                                        onItemClick:function(){
                                                webix.message("Values of textarea is "+$$('textarea').getValue());
                        webix.ajax().post("submit.php");
                                     }
                                },
      "labelPosition": "top"

    }

  ]
                        });     
        });

        </script>
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
<input type="submit" name="f_1">
</form>

<input type="checkbox" name="marks" id="marks" />
<input type="text" name="studentMarks" id="studentMarks">

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my **submit.php**:

```
<?php
//include 'scriptss2.php';
require_once('functions.php');
   saveToFileWithVar();
echo "It works";
header( 'Location: index.php');
?>
```

Here is my function.php:

```
<?php
function saveToFileWithVar()
{
if ($_POST['WO_textarea'] != ''){
   echo $_POST['WO_textarea']; //textarea! е \n \r
   echo nl2br($_POST['WO_textarea']); //textarea! html с сохранением пробелов и переносов строк
}else die('Please enter WO number(s)!');
$filename = getcwd() . "/data/data.php";
echo $filename;
$testVar = 'Huy6';
$line_i_am_looking_for = 16;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
//$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = ($_POST['WO_textarea']+'tettr');
$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = ('$data->render_sql("SELECT idWO, WO_STATUS FROM GENERIC_TABLES.WO WHERE idWO IN ('.$$('textarea').getValue().')", "", "idWO, WO_STATUS");');
//$lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = ('$data->render_sql("SELECT idWO, WO_STATUS FROM GENERIC_TABLES.WO WHERE idWO IN ('.$_POST['WO_textarea'].')", "", "idWO, WO_STATUS");');
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
echo $testVar;
echo ('$data->render_sql("SELECT idWO, WO_STATUS FROM GENERIC_TABLES.WO WHERE idWO IN ('.$_POST['WO_textarea'].')", "", "idWO, WO_STATUS");');
}
?>
```

So, what I want to do - when I click **Passss** button, it shoud take text from textarea (which I can do easily with `$$('textarea').getValue())` function).

I need to add this value to below string:

```
 $lines[$line_i_am_looking_for] = ('$data->render_sql("SELECT idWO, WO_STATUS FROM GENERIC_TABLES.WO WHERE idWO IN ('.$$('textarea').getValue().')", "", "idWO, WO_STATUS");');
```

Now I would like to pass this variable to function.php, but I can't do it.
I believe there can be small mistype but I can't see it.